# Load specific part of html page

Tags: android, web, http-get

If I have to show in my web view a specific part of a web page how can i solve this problem?

for example I need, in the web URL `http://www.example.com/` the specific part contained between `<body>..</body>`

Comment: Thats a nice task for a webview. A webview is specialised to display all between the body tags. Just give the webview the url and all will flow.

Comment: There aren't any method to solve this problem?

Comment: Thats no problem as i have explained. That's a fine solution. You are done. Problem solved. That's what i said.

Comment: .. the body tag was an example.. if i need for example only the head class i havent solved my problem.

Comment: If you could extract the head tag and present it to a webview then what do you think you would see?